# Disable the drop down menu of a WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ComboBox as specified below:

```
<ComboBox Height="31" Margin="7,7,0,0" Name="callerID" IsEditable="True"  Background="LightBlue" KeyDown="callerIDbar_KeyDown" Foreground="White" FontSize="17"  FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  />
```

`storedCalls` is a collection of phone numbers that will be populated to the `ComboBox.Items`:

```
foreach (string call in storedCalls)
{
   if (call != "Enter a number to dial")
      callerID.Items.Add(call);
}
```

All this works fine.  I populate the `Items` primary because I like the autocomplete that is driven by the values in the `ComboBox`'s `Items` collections.  Is there a way the XAML to disable the drop down error, and disable the drop down menu?  I.e. make a simple auto complete textbox like control?

I have seen full on `TextBox` controls that include a bunch of code-behind and complicated markup, and this is not what I am looking to do.  I just need to disable the ability of the drop down menu from showing.

Comment: I believe you'll have to change the template. And from what I've seen, it is kinda huge...

Comment: You're looking for an `AutoCompleteTextBox`. You can find one in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535). BTW, don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. Create a proper ViewModel for this.

Comment: @Tico can you elaborate slightly on changing the template and what it might entail?  I'm not a dedicated full time WPF developer.

Comment: @HighCore, yeah I was afraid I might have to include another resource or use a control that is already baked.  Asking SO was my last effort before going this route.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @kmarks2 if you right click your `ComboBox -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy...` You'll see how the Control was designed. But since you already said that you're not a full time WPF developer, that might be extremely hard for now!. HighCore suggestion might be your answer!

Comment: I would go with HighCore's suggestion, but if you're dead set on a combobox a quick and easy workaround could be to just set the `MaxDropDownHeight` property to 0 and fake it.

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks, it's the only reasonably quick/easy way to do it it seems.

Answer (score 5):

You can handle the `DropDownOpened` event and then close it.
So in n the XAML you get:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" DropDownOpened="cb_DropDownOpened"/>
```

And in Code Behind:

```
private void cbCategoria_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
        cb.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
```

I prefear this solution reather than set `MaxDropDownHeight` to 0.
Your choice.

Comment: This works better than setting ComboBox's Enabled property to false.